# RabbitMQ difference between exclusive and auto-delete?

Tags: rabbitmq

The "RabbitMQ in Action" book on page 19 gives these descriptions of exclusive and auto-delete:

> exclusive - When set to true, your queue becomes private and can only
>   be consumed by your app. This is useful when you need to limit a queue
>   to only one consumer.
>
> auto-delete - The queue is automatically deleted when the last
>   consumer unsubscribes. If you need a temporary queue used only by one
>   consumer, combine auto-delete with exclusive. When the consumer
>   disconnects, the queue will be removed.

But as far as I can see when using exclusive, auto-delete is redundant. Only exclusive is needed. The RabbitMQ [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) seems to say that is the case

> ...once we disconnect the consumer the queue should be deleted. There's
>   an exclusive flag for that:

```
result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
```

There is no mention in that tutorial about auto-delete and `sudo rabbitmqctl list_bindings` seems to indicate that the queue is in fact deleted after the receiver goes away.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Well, it is true that `exclusive` queues will auto-delete when the consumer disconnects (see the [documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.exclusive) pasted below). However, there are cases when you want queues to be non-exclusive, yet still auto-delete (for example, if I want to add another consumer).

> **exclusive**
>
> Exclusive queues may only be accessed by the current connection, and are deleted when that connection closes. Passive declaration of an exclusive queue by other connections are not allowed.
>
> **auto-delete**
>
> If set, the queue is deleted when all consumers have finished using
> it. The last consumer can be cancelled either explicitly or because
> its channel is closed. If there was no consumer ever on the queue, it
> won't be deleted. Applications can explicitly delete auto-delete
> queues using the Delete method as normal.

Personally, I prefer to use neither of these parameters, instead opting for the RabbitMQ [queue expiration](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl) parameter, which is better if I have a consumer disconnect and then re-connect immediately (or a short time) later; messages are not lost in this case. But, of course it all depends upon your application and requirements.

Comment: But the link says "are deleted when that connection closes" (and says nothing about consumers).

Comment: Yes, that is correct for `exclusive` - the question dealt with the difference between `exclusive` and `auto-delete` - and hopefully I was able to illustrate that there is an important difference and valid scenarios when you might want to use both.

Answer (score 22):

In contrast to [what theMayer described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21249132), my testing showed that there is a difference in behavior when auto-delete is toggled while exclusive is set to true.

If auto-delete is set to false, the queue is indeed tied to the connection and will disappear when the connection is terminated.

If auto-delete is set to true, the queue will be deleted after the last consumer is cancelled.

There is a difference between a connection and a consumer. You can be connected, but not consuming a given queue. If you need the queue's lifecycle to be tied to your connection rather than to whether or not you're actively consuming it, set auto-delete to false in conjunction with exclusive=true.

Comment: This is entirely consistent with the documentation. I believe the issue is that the question references some third-party source, and that source is not exactly accurate. It would have been better if that book simply quoted from the documentation, but it chose to paraphrase, and did so poorly, thus creating the question.