# RabbitMQ difference between expires and auto-delete?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

The "RabbitMQ in Action" book on page 19 gives these descriptions of exclusive and auto-delete:

> auto-delete - The queue is automatically deleted when the last
>   consumer unsubscribes. If you need a temporary queue used only by one
>   consumer, combine auto-delete with exclusive. When the consumer
>   disconnects, the queue will be removed.

Then, in https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html, gives expeire description:

> expires policy controls for how long a queue can
>   be unused before it is automatically deleted. Unused means the queue
>   has no consumers, the queue has not been recently redeclared
>   (redeclaring renews the lease),and basic.get has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ difference between exclusive and auto-delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248563/rabbitmq-difference-between-exclusive-and-auto-delete)

Answer (score 7):

**expalation for [auto-delete](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html):** the queue is deleted when all consumers have finished using it. The last consumer can be cancelled either explicitly or because its channel is closed. If there was no consumer ever on the queue, it won't be deleted. Applications can explicitly delete auto-delete queues using the Delete method.

**explanation for [expires](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl):** Expiry time can be set for a given queue by setting the x-expires argument to queue.declare, or by setting the expires policy. This controls for how long a queue can be unused before it is automatically deleted. Unused means the queue has no consumers, the queue has not been recently redeclared (redeclaring renews the lease), and basic.get has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period. This can be used, for example, for RPC-style reply queues, where many queues can be created which may never be drained.

I think it would be better to use expires instead of auto-delete because if somehting happens and the subscriber went down for a short time then the msg will not be lost that's a big advantage of using expires and that explains simply the difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

The plain and simple answer here is that *exclusive/auto-delete* will delete the queue **immediately after the first consumer has disconnected**, while *expires* will delete the queue **after a period of inactivity** regardless of consumer(s) having connected to it in the past.

Comment: Is it really "first consumer" but not last consumer?

Comment: @blackr1234 On an exclusive queue, there can only be one consumer, so the first consumer is also the last consumer.